# Override receiver type in test and dependency-inject into logic

Tags: go

Using `Go v1.14.3`, I'm trying to do the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/mihaigalos/go-bar/bar"
)

var progressBar bar.Bar

func (*ProgressHandler) New(begin int, end int) {
    progressBar.New(begin, end)
}

func main() {
    var progressHandler ProgressHandler
    send(&progressHandler)
}
```

So far so good. But when I test, I have no need to see any progressbar, hence my ProgressHandler can be empty, and I want to dependency-inject this object into `send()`.
Inside it will call my specified `New()`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
)
func (*ProgressHandler) New(int, int) {
}

func TestSendWorks_whenTypical(t *testing.T) {
    expected := true
    var progressHandler ProgressHandler

    actual := send(&progressHandler)

    if actual != expected {
        t.Errorf("No Match: %b != %b", actual, expected)
    }
}
```

When I compile this, I get a name collision with the handlers defined in `main`:

```sh
integration_typical_test.go:23:25: (*ProgressHandler).New redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at main.go:15:6
```

I've tried changing the name of the package to something different. The same error there.
How can I improve here?

Comment: Have the argument to `send` be an interface e.g. `type P interface{ New(int,int) }`; have two separate progress handler types that implement that interface, one for live code one for testing, and you're done. Alternative, have `New` exit early if receiver is `nil`, pass `nil` in tests, and you're done (you can invoke methods on non-interface `nil` receivers in case you didn't know).

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'm trying to implemet something now. Can you provide an example so as I can approve the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an *interface*.

```golang
type ProgressBar interface {
    New(int, int)
}

var progressBar bar.Bar

// New implements ProgressBar
func (*ProgressHandler) New(begin int, end int) {
    progressBar.New(begin, end)
}

// change *ProgressHandler to ProgressBar
func send(pb ProgressBar) {
    // ...
}

func main() {
    var progressHandler ProgressHandler
    send(&progressHandler)
}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

type fakeProgressHandler struct{}

func (*fakeProgressHandler) New(int, int) {
}

func TestSendWorks_whenTypical(t *testing.T) {
    expected := true
    var progressHandler fakeProgressHandler

    actual := send(&progressHandler)

    if actual != expected {
        t.Errorf("No Match: %b != %b", actual, expected)
    }
}
```

---

Handle `nil` receiver in the handler.

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/mihaigalos/go-bar/bar"
)

var progressBar bar.Bar

func (h *ProgressHandler) New(begin int, end int) {
    if h == nil {
        return
    }
    progressBar.New(begin, end)
}

func main() {
    var progressHandler ProgressHandler
    send(&progressHandler)
}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSendWorks_whenTypical(t *testing.T) {
    expected := true

    actual := send(nil)

    if actual != expected {
        t.Errorf("No Match: %b != %b", actual, expected)
    }
}
```